# php/css error, don`t load Style to some objects

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I got some strange problems with my php-code
when I try to output this `echo "<div class='button menu' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI'\">Menu</div>";`

sometimes it don´t load the css, even not the **div** -tags, just the plain "Menu" string
and it´s always printed before my **table** -tags

how is this possible?

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
$root_dir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>";
if (!isset($_GET['command'])) {
    echo "<div class='button' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI?command=show'\">Personaldaten anzeigen</div>";
    //echo "<div class='button' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI?command=new'\">neue Person anlegen</div>";
    //echo "<div class='button' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI?command=work'\">Personaldaten bearbeiten</div>";
} else {
    if ($_GET['command'] == "show") {
        openSQL();
        $sqlbefehl = 'select * from kontakt';
        @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $ergebnis = @mysql_query($sqlbefehl); // SQL-Befehl an die Datenbank schicken
        $spalten  = @mysql_num_fields($ergebnis);
        echo "<table class='style'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $spalten; $i++) {
            echo "<th class='th'>" . mysql_field_name($ergebnis, $i) . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        while (false != ($row = mysql_fetch_row($ergebnis))) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($row); $i++) {
                echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table";
    }
    echo "<div class='button menu' onclick=\"javascript:location.href='$baseURI'\">Menu</div>";
}
function openSQL()
{
    $server   = "127.0.0.1";
    $user     = "root";
    $passwort = "";
    $db       = "schule";
    $dblink   = @mysql_connect($server, $user, $passwort);
    if (!@mysql_select_db($db)) {
        echo "<br>Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank $db möglich!";
        echo "<br>" . mysql_error();
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

CSS-Code:

```
body{
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;

}
.style{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

.style table,.style th,.style td {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.style td {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.button{
    height: 68px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px orange solid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.menu{
    height: 36px;
    width: 75px;
}
.delBtn{
    height: 36px;
    width: 95px;
}
.del{
    background-image: url(del.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.edit{
    background-image: url(edit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width:24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

Comment: you're mixing together tags that should not be. <link> elements should go into the <head> section while most tags (<div>, etc) should go into the <body>. Consider using an html validator to inform you about potential other issues.

Comment: Can you include a `var_dump` of the `$baseURI` variable? I don't see it being set anywhere :p

Comment: can you provide live link??

Comment: I will post the output DOM soon as possible
your right, `$baseURI` is undefined
will test it at home, can´t get xampp to work here

Comment: I spot your `table` tag not closed properly.  The echo to closing `</table>` missing '>'.

Comment: @Calimero I tested in newest Chrome and Mozilla and it seems to me like the browsers interpret normaly the <link> as header section and the <div> in the <body>
I have to post the DOM

Comment: @cwps thanks hope, this is the solution 
will test it

Comment: Include the stylesheet link in the header, you're loading it in the body now, which is wrong. That's why it doesn't work. It doesn't get loaded properly.

Comment: thanks @all, it was the missing '>' after my closing `table` tag 
also my `$baseURI` was not setup
I fixed it and now it work
@KeesSonnema with the closed table, the DOM look good to me 
    `<html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Im answering my own Question. It was the missing ">" at the closing table-tag. Since I fixed the missing character, the code now work properly.

Thanks for all of your effort <3